# Deployment script takes around 30 min on magento 2.4.5-p1. how to reduce the time?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, static-content-deploy, deployment

When I run the deployment command on our production mode site, it takes around 30 mins to complete. How can I make it faster?

Magento Version: 2.4.5-p1

Comment: Which comments you are using.Please share

Comment: php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy